# Node.js unzipper+request. Ошибка FILE_ENDED

Tags: node.js, request

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Локально код работает, но на сервере в кластере код выдает ошибку FILE_ENDED.
Стоит корпоративный прокси. Переменные http_proxy, https_proxy, no_proxy установлены.

**src/index.ts / lib/index.js**

```
import request from "request"
import unzipper from "unzipper"
import { ClientRequest } from "http"

;(async () => {
  const directory = await unzipper.Open.url(
    (request as unknown) as ClientRequest,
    "http://file.nalog.ru/opendata/7707329152-rsmp/data-07102020-structure-15052020.zip"
  )
  
  console.log(directory.files[0])
})()
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build && npm prune --production


FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/node_modules node_modules/
COPY --from=build /app/lib lib/

CMD [ "node", "lib" ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в настройках сервера. Прокси не пускало через http, заменил http на https в URL и все заработало.